# I read a line on a csv file and want to know the item number of a word

Tags: python-3.x

The header line in my csv file is:

```
Number,Name,Type,Manufacturer,Material,Process,Thickness (mil),Weight (oz),Dk,Orientation,Pullback distance (mil),Description
```

I can open it and read the line, with no problems:

```
infile = open('CS_Data/_AD_LayersTest.csv','r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
for row in csv_reader:
```

But I want to find out what the item number is for the "Dk".

The problem is that not only can the items be in any order as decided by the user in a different application. There can also be up to 25 items in the line.

How do I quickly determine what item is "Dk" so I can write Dk = (row[i]) for it and extract it for all the data after the header.

I have tried this below on each of the potential 25 items and it works, but it seems like a waste of time, energy and my ocd.

```
while True:
    try:
        if (row[0]) == "Dk":
            DkColumn = 0
            break
        elif (row[1]) == "Dk":
            DkColumn = 1
            break
    ...
        elif (row[24]) == "Dk":
            DkColumn = 24
            break
        else:
            f.write('Stackup needs a "Dk" column.')
            break
    except:
        print ("Exception occurred")
        break
```

Comment: Do you explicitly not want to use pandas, or are you new to python and haven't used pandas yet. If you want to non-pandas solution consider adding that to the question, since some of the solutions below are valid, and easy, if you use pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you get the index of the column (using [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)) that has the value `Dk` in it? Something like:

```
infile = open('CS_Data/_AD_LayersTest.csv','r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')

# Store the header 
headers = next(csv_reader, None)

# Get the index of the 'Dk' column
dkColumnIndex = header.index('Dk')

for row in csv_reader:

  # Access values that belong to the 'Dk' column
  rowDkValue = row[dkColumnIndex]

  print(rowDkValue)
```

In the code above, we store the first line of the CSV in as a list in `headers`. We then search the list to find the index of the item that has the value of `'Dk'`. That will be the column index.

Once we have that column index, we can then use it in each row to access the particular index, which will correspond to the column which `Dk` is the header of.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I need. I will try it and let you know. Sorry, I am a newbie and wasn't aware of the index function.

Comment: I tried each of the suggestions and I have decided to use this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas` library to save your order and have access to each column by typing:
`row["column_name"]`

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv(
       "", 
       cols=["Number","Name","Type" ....])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # do something
```

Comment: Ok. I need to try this as well. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, and you're not interested in using pandas (as suggested by Mikey - you sohuld really consider his suggestion, however), you should be able to do something like the following:

```
with open('CS_Data/_AD_LayersTest.csv','r') as infile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(csv_reader)
    col_map = {col_name: idx for idx, col_name in enumerate(header)}
    for row in csv_reader:
        row_dk = row[col_map['Dk']]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('CS_Data/_AD_LayersTest.csv')
```

Now you can access 'Dk' easily as long as the file is read correctly.

```
dk=df['Dk']
```

and you can access individual values of dk like

```
for i in range(0,10):
    temp_var=df.loc('Dk',i)
```

or however you want to access those indexes.